# Does properties order matter?

Tags: html, css

If I have an exemplary div:

```
#div {
max-height: 100px;
height: auto
}
```

vs.

```
#div {
height: auto;
max-height: 100px;
}
```

Does it make an difference in an output file?

Comment: No sir! + height: auto; doesn't matter

Comment: Nop, I mean the output will be the same unless it is being overridden by some other styles or it is overriding some other styles.

Answer (score 5):

Order *does* matter in some cases. For instance, when using vendor-prefixed versions together with W3 compliant properties.

```
-webkit-transform: ;
transform ;
```

vs.

```
transform: ;
-webkit-transform: ;
```

The browser will use the last property. So always use the W3C compliant property **last** if it's available!

Comment: also when you use a specific property followed by its shorthand e.g. `background-image` and `background`

Answer (score 3):

in your scenario no. But others yes. For example:

```
.add-margin {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 5px /** element will have 5px on left margin **/
}
```

vs

```
.add-margin {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin: 0 /** element will have no margins **/
}
```

as a general rule of thumb, I place all my properties alphabetically unless a special case is needed - this ensures overrides get added correctly (as in case of my first example of code)

Answer (score 1):

As per your scenario properties order not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the developers has no specific plan when it comes to ordering CSS. But I personally suggest a method based on how much impact they have on the selected elements or other elements around them.

- Layout Properties (position, float, clear, display)
- Box Model Properties (width, height, margin, padding)
- Visual Properties (color,background,border,box-shadow)
- Typography Properties (font-size,font-family,text-align,text-transform)
- Misc Properties (cursor,overflow,z-index)

I came to read this during my research on some css coding standards. You could read more [here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/outside-in-ordering-css-properties-by-importance--cms-21685)

Comment: Even though these are good hints, it does not answer the question.

Comment: As I said, on SO a question is expected to answer the question. Otherwise it is not a valid answer - hence the downvote. Please don't take it personal. Instead, you could just comment on the post with the url you linked.

Comment: @BramVanroy sure. not at all personal :).  There was a time i struggled to find answer to the same question. You can do as per stackoverflow standards. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, Properties order does not matter until and unless you are not modifying the same property and you want to switch between the available two or many.

**Example:**

```
#div{
    color: red;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 20px;
}
#div{
    color: blue;
}
```

So, in this case, the colour properties are replaced by the last one and the colour will be **blue** but for the height and max-height the same properties which are assigned in the first place will be reflected and until and unless they are not overwritten.

Comment: but as a note, you should never do this (specify multiple #id tags in a stylesheet to override, just set it once)